# What happens when you use Cache-Control: max-age with ETags?

Tags: http, caching, browser, http-headers, etag

There are several similar questions, but none of the ones I've found are clear or definitive.

Here's the behavior I want:

- As long as the network is available, the browser **must** check if there's a new version
- If there isn't a new version, the browser can use the cached version
- The cached version expires after X days

I think I can do this with `Cache-Control: max-age` and ETags. However, I can't find whether the max-age should be `0` or how long the content should be cached for.

E.g. if I do `Cache-Control: max-age=86400` (1 day) with an ETag, would it:

1. Make a server request every time, but the server will just return 304 if the ETag didn't change. After 1 day, discard the cached version, and refetch from the server (which should be the same as the discarded version).
2. Doesn't make any server requests for a day. Then, after 1 day, the server can still return 304. The cached version can stay indefinitely.

I'd like the browser to refetch after X days because in case there's a bug, I don't want users stuck with a broken cached version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's the behavior I want:
>
> - As long as the network is available, the browser **must** check if there's a new version
> - If there isn't a new version, the browser can use the cached version

This is a common use case, and can be accomplished by using `Cache-Control: no-cache` (or `max-age=0, must-revalidate`) and providing an `ETag` or `Last-Modified` header.

> - The cached version expires after X days

This is not possible. It's not part of the design of HTTP caching because there's no use case for it.

> I'd like the browser to refetch after X days because in case there's a bug, I don't want users stuck with a broken cached version.

If the browser is checking for a new version each time, how can the user ever get stuck with a "broken" cached version?

> If I do `Cache-Control: max-age=86400` (1 day) with an ETag, would it:
>
> 1. Make a server request every time, but the server will just return 304 if the ETag didn't change. After 1 day, discard the cached version, and refetch from the server (which should be the same as the discarded version).
> 2. Doesn't make any server requests for a day. Then, after 1 day, the server can still return 304. The cached version can stay indefinitely.

Number 2. The `max-age` tells the browser how long it  can consider the resource to be *fresh*, meaning that the cached version can be used without checking with the server. When that time has expired, the resource is considered *stale*, and a new request has to be made. If the cached resource has an `ETag` or `Last Modified` header that request can be a *conditional* one to allow the server to avoid sending the entire resource in the response.

Comment: A use case could be a bug where ETags are generated incorrectly, so the server always returns 304 even though the content changed. I had a bug before where users were stuck with stale scripts for a long time, forgot what happened

Comment: @LeoJiang: What probably happened in that case, and what is somewhat common, is that the `max-age` was set for a long time. That's a real problem, because there's nothing the server can do at that point to force the browser to request a new version. In the case of incorrect `ETags`, by contrast, the server is in control and as soon as the bug is fixed the very next request will work correctly. So it's really not a problem.