# Caching strategy using ETag and Expires/Cache-control with no assets version/ID

Tags: http, browser-cache, cache-control, etag

After reading a lot about caching validators (more intensively after reading [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7762952/2477831)), I had a doubt that didn't find the answer anywhere.

My use-case is to serve a static asset (a javascript file, ie: `https://example.com/myasset.js`) to be used in other websites, so *messing* with their Gpagespeed/gmetrix score matters the most.
I also need **their users to receive updated versions of my static asset every time I deploy new changes**.

For this, I have the following response headers:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=10800
etag: W/"4efa5de1947fe4ce90cf10992fa"
```

##### In short, we can see the following flow in terms of how browser behaves using `etag`

For the first request, the browser has no value for the `If-None-Match` Request Header, so the Server will send back the status code 200 (Ok), the content itself, and a Response header with ETag value.

[image: first request with no etag]

For the subsequent requests, the browser will add the previously received ETag value in a form of the `If-None-Match` Request Header. This way, the server can compare this value with the current value from ETag and, if both match, the server can return 304 (Not Modified) telling the browser to use the latest version of the file, or just 200 followed by the new content and the related ETag value instead.

[image: subsequent requests]

**However**, I couldn't find any information in regards to using the `Cache-Control: max-age` header and how will this affect the above behavior, like:

1. Will the browser request for new updates **before** `max-age` has met? Meaning that I can define a higher `max-age` value (pagespeed/gmetrix will be happy about it) and *force* this refresh using only `etag` fingerprint.
2. If not, then what are the advantages of using `etag` and adding extra bits to the network?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when you use Cache-Control: max-age with ETags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68092519/what-happens-when-you-use-cache-control-max-age-with-etags)

Answer (score 0):

1. No, the browser will not send any requests until `max-age` has passed.
2. The advantage of using `ETag` is that, if the file hasn't changed, you don't need to resend the entire file to the client. The response will be a small `304`.

Note that you can achieve the best of both worlds by using the [`stale-while-revalidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#response_directives) directive, which allows stale responses to be served while the cache silently revalidates the resource in the background.

Comment: If the browser holds the asset in the local cache, it will do the exact same request and see a `304` being returned, as visible when using `etag` validator. Am I missing something?

Comment: @fiskolin: I'm not sure I understand your question, but without an `ETag` (or `Last-Modified`) on the response there won't be a conditional request, and therefore there can't be a `304`.